# What are the differences between these two generic classes?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

At the moment I am learning TypeScript, and I have a question about **Generic Classes**.

Can you explain to me the difference between these two examples?

```js
class MathCalc<T extends number, U extends number> {
    constructor(private x: T, private y:U){}

    add(): number {
        return this.x + this.y;
    }

    sub(): number {
        return this.x - this.y;
    }
}
```

and

```js
class CMathCalc {
    constructor(private x: number, private y: number) {}

    add(): number {
        return this.x + this.y;
    }

    sub(): number {
        return this.x - this.y;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The first one actually allows you to set limits and not allow *any* number: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyYBcAWBhMJgB4Aq0CmAHgngHYAmMJArgLYBGeATgDTQCq+RpF019TAPmgBvALAAoaFOjAA9iQgJGVYAlmMAFAAdGASwBuiPNAIAuaNlY6DR6AE9TbAJTCAvhInToYMmQ1PzPgZGEU8vaUY8BCpGEmhkXQgAOgJoAGp4pESkuwBuMKl3cQLoCCo6f0DaYNDJcKlI6NjM7NSAWhbkvJKiook5BQQZdGAARmgAXl48AHc4RFQRzAAWAAZWACYBDWXRzadc6AB6I5nGeQBzfvlFYYwNyem5+GQ0DBX16C2dz4BmA+Op3OJCu4gGt2AI1+jxIs3mryWa022yRXwBJzkjEiqg8YJushAeCSIFkFw0kIwvySPj8TicQA)

Comment: I think this is not the best example to explain generics. I found [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/typescript-generics-in-typescript) a good explanation.

Comment: You don't really gain much from extending a primitive, so this example doesn't really do much.